# Converting a list of lists of strings to a data frame of numbers in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, mapply

I have a list of lists of strings as follows:

```
> ll

[[1]]
[1] "2" "1"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "1"

[[4]]
[1] "1" "8"
```

The longest list is of length 2, and I want to build a data frame with 2 columns from this list. Bonus points for also converting each item in the list to a number or NA for character(0). I have tried using mapply() and data.frame to convert to a data frame and fill with NA's as follows.

```
#  Find length of each list element
len = sapply(awards2, length)

#  Number of NAs to fill for column shorter than longest
len = 2 - len

df = data.frame(mapply( function(x,y) c( x , rep( NA , y ) ) , ll , len))
```

However, I do not get a data frame with 2 columns (and NA's as fillers) using the code above.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `sapply(ll, '[', 1:max(lengths(ll)))`

Comment: @d.b, the number of columns is known, so you can just use `length<-` instead: `t(sapply(ll, \`length<-\`, 2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`.  As the `list` elements are all `character` vectors, it seems okay to use this function

```
library(stringi)
t(stri_list2matrix(ll))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "2"  "1" 
#[2,] NA   NA  
#[3,] "1"  NA  
#[4,] "1"  "8"
```

If we need to convert to `data.frame`, wrap it with `as.data.frame`

Comment: Thanks again Akrun! I think I need to learn these string packages that you are using.