# R - Unstack a dataframe and create a new dataframe with 2 columns only

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following goal and having a hard to find other posts here that talk about the same thing.
My basic code is the following:

```
df = data.frame(cusip=c("A","B","C","D","A","C","Z","A","B"),
                port=c("p1","p1","p1","p1","p2","p2","p2","p3","p3"))
```

... do something and get the following dataframe:
rows = unique values in column 'port'
column = just one column showing (with a string) all the unique cusip values associated to the portfolio specified in the first column.
Hence, the result should look like this:

```
df2 = data.frame(port=c("p1","p2","p3"),
                cusip=c("A, B C, D",    "A, C, Z",   "A, B"))
```

I tried to do something like:

```
u = unstack(df1)
```

However, this gives me now a list where every name of the list corresponds to a unique portfolio id and each element of the list contains a vector of undefined length with all the cusip values associated to the portfolio.
So at this point I'm a little lost.
I read this solution [Converting a list of lists of strings to a data frame of numbers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42514249/converting-a-list-of-lists-of-strings-to-a-data-frame-of-numbers-in-r) that explains how to convert a list back to dataframe, however it doesn't really help me since the number of cusips associated to any given portfolio is unknown.
Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr` and `stringr` is

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(port) %>% 
  summarise(cusip = stringr::str_c(cusip, collapse = ", "))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  port  cusip     
  <fct> <chr>     
1 p1    A, B, C, D
2 p2    A, C, Z   
3 p3    A, B
```

Comment: wow! thank you so much! I spent almost an hour on this trying to convert the list of vectors into a dataframe. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

A `base R` solution can be done with `aggregate()` like this:

```
#Code
aggregate(cusip~port,df,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ', '))
```

Output:

```
  port      cusip
1   p1 A, B, C, D
2   p2    A, C, Z
3   p3       A, B
```

Comment: `aggregate(cusip~port,df, paste0,collapse = ', ')` or even `aggregate(cusip~port,df,toString)`

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `toString`

```
aggregate(cusip ~ port, df, toString)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(cusip = toString(cusip)), port]
```